# Tamanho da coluna GRID Bootstrap - Valor customizado

Tags: bootstrap, grid, css

Saudações!

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz quanto a imagem abaixo ... 
A questão X é que eu preciso de um meio termo neste alinhamento.
Se eu ponho col-md-1 corta o input se eu coloco col-md-2 fica muito grande.

Tentei usar span mas piora a situção com o bootsptrap-switch :( ficando desalinhando horizontalmente.

[]'s

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Creio que só mesmo ajustando manualmente nos seus css

Comment: Coloque o col-md-1 mesmo e crie uma outra classe para ajustar o tamanho.

Comment: Já tentou "col-sm-1" ou "col-xs-1"?

Answer (score 3):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado a todos mas acabei resolvendo adicionando um stylezinho ... como é um ponto especifico ficou mais fácil e simples esta solução ..

Answer (score 0):

Os valores das larguras das colunas do bootstrap são definidos em termos de porcentagem, além de ser responsivos. Se col-md-1 ficou muito pequeno, provavelmente a sua visualização é que é pequena. Para melhorar o uso da largura, utiliza a classe container-fluid na div que envelopa todo o site para ocupar o máximo possível de área.

Mesmo assim, é preferível que você utilize um tamanho de 12 colunas para o rótulo e outras 12 para o campo input. Fica mais fácil de visualizar em desktops pequenos.